# How to convert an integer to binary form in Go and vice versa

Tags: binary, integer, go

How do i convert an Integer to binary form?

I'm currently working on a program that takes an integer and converts it to binary form.
It should also take the binary number and reverse it and convert it back to an integer and print it out.

i.e.

> `12 -> 1100 -> 0011 -> 3`

So the program should basically:
Input: 12
Output: 3

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

var j int

func main() {
    fmt.Scan(&j)
    n := int64(j)
    y := strconv.FormatInt(n, 2)
    fmt.Println(y)
    reverse(y)
}

func reverse(y string) {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use [encoding/binary](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/).

Example ([goplay](http://play.golang.org/p/P_pqIZHC-m)):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/binary"
import "bytes"

func main() {
    j := int32(5247)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, j)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    var k int32
    err = binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &k)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(k)
}
```